# Laravel : Multi Guard in Auth Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Application using Multi User tables for different roles.

I have added 2 custom guards like this:

```
'guards' => [
    'consumer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'consumer',
    ],
    'member' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'member',
    ]
]
```

And I want to share the the same route with both of consumer and member. But I dont know how Laravel pass guard name to the Auth middleware.

Look at file `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`

```
protected function authenticate(array $guards)
{
    if (empty($guards)) {
        return $this->auth->authenticate();
    }

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
            return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
        }
    }

    throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);
}
```

If I can pass 2 custom guards to the $guards variable, It can share the route between custom and user. But I dont know how to pass the guard's name

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can just pass the guards with comma, for exapmle:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:comsumer, member'] ], function(){
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    });
```

Comment: You save my life :D

Comment: remember to avoid whitespaces:

`'auth:comsumer,member']`

Comment: but what if I need to give the member `->only('show')`?

Answer (score 2):

While defining the route group do something like this,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:guard_name'], function () {
    //Your Route goes here
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.