# laravel auth::attempt not saving session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I want to build multiple guards login system using single sign in page for all guards, so, I overwritten the `attemptLogin` function in `LoginController` as follow:

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request){
 if(Auth::guard('marketer')->attempt($request->only('email','password'),$request->filled('remember'))){
            //Authentication passed...
//            dd();
            return redirect()
                ->intended(url('/home'))
                ->with('status','You are Logged in as marketer!');
        }
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password'),$request->filled('remember'))){
            //Authentication passed...
//            dd(session()->all());
            return redirect()
                ->intended(url('/home'))
                ->with('status','You are Logged in as admin!');
        }
return $this->loginFailed();
}
```

and I set up admin in admins table, when trying to login using the correct email and password and when I uncomment `dd(session()->all());` I see Laravel is generating session, but, once I comment `dd(session()->all());` and try `Auth::check()` I get `false`.

it seems either Laravel is not persisting the session or it is regenerating it in such way `Auth::check` return `false`.

what is the problem? how to fix it?

Comment: @ArunAS the command you gived is returning true, but, when route is protected by auth middleware then should not the admin be able to view that route? take for example /home

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant, but do ensure that you specify all guard names on the `/home` route. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40859225/4516316)

Comment: @ArunAS that is the answer I am looking for, if you like please write your answer so I accept it