# Laravel conditionally auth against multiple guards

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I have set up where we have 3 different types of users. All three of which is done with jwt auth via this package: https://github.com/PHP-Open-Source-Saver/jwt-auth

We have 3 guard, 3 providers something like:

```
<?php
return [

'guards' => [

   'vendors' => [
          'driver' => 'jwt',
          'provider' => 'vendorUsers',
      ],
      'admins' => [
          'driver' => 'jwt',
          'provider' => 'adminUsers',
      ],
      'customers' => [
          'driver' => 'jwt',
          'provider' => 'customerUsers',
      ],
],

'providers' => [
      'vendorUsers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Api\Models\VendorUser::class,
        'resource' =>  App\Http\Resources\VendorUserResource::class,
      ],
      'adminUsers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Api\Models\AdminUser::class  ),
        'resource' => App\Http\Resources\AdminUserResource::class,
      ],
      'customerUsers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' =>  Api\Models\CustomerUser::class  ,
        'resource' =>  App\Http\Resources\CustomerUserResource::class,
      ],
  ],
];
```

In our routes file we want to be able to specify somehow "auth against either adminUsers OR vendorUsers" ... OR "auth against any of of these providers"

Was thinking something like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:vendors,customers,admin'] ], function(){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:vendors,admin'] ], function(){
    Route::get('/special-access', 'HomeController@special-access');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin'] ], function(){
    Route::get('/admins-only', 'HomeController@admins');
});
```

following the advice of [Laravel : Multi Guard in Auth Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670722/laravel-multi-guard-in-auth-middleware) would allow use to conditionally auth against any of the specified guards but this is not the case; the comma in the auth middleware part of of the route definition acts as an "AND" not an "OR".

Is something like this even possible or what are my options to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, unfortunately, mainly due to this being more of an Architecture issue. When you define 3 different models for what is essentially a User, you run into these kinds of issues. A User is a User. You can give a User different Roles (one, or multiple), which you can then tie to middleware/guards to allow/restrict access, but you still use a single point of truth for Authentication, which is the `User.php` model, using a single `users` table. I'd be very interested if you can get this to work, since in my experience, this has never turned out well 

Comment: the `auth` middleware spins through all the guards passed until it finds one that returns a user ... so it is an OR not an AND